# Why is my input validation from jquery wont work?

Tags: javascript, php, validation, input

I want a validation onkeyup from an input form, I've made a jquery. I'm having a hard time finding why is it not checking? I need to go to a php page in checking. What could be wrong to my code that it don't work?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
reg
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" onkeyup="check_user()" id="name"/><div id="checking">Checking</div>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit<button> 
</form>


<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true;
function check_user(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

     $.post("user_check.php",
     {
         user: name
     },
     function(data,status){
         if(data=='<p style="color:red">Name contains a number</p>'){
             document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true;
         }
         else{
             document.getElementById("submit").disabled=false;
         }
         document.getElementById("checking").innerHTML=data;    
     }

     );

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

user_check.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {    
    if(preg_match('/^\d+$/', $_POST['user'])) {
        echo '<p style="color:red">Name contains a number</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p style="color:green"> You can take this name</p>';
    }    
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you define not working? What is happening?

Comment: The word cheking won't change

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the text box by adding the pattern attribute like this pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"

```
  <input type="text" name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"  title="please just add strings"  id="name"/>
```

i also notice in your code you did not add the id for the submit button thats why your submit button is not disabled, your code should like this for submit button.
      Submit

Comment: This is only UI validation. OP wants to perform AJAX for server-side validation. They are not exactly the same.

Comment: please first add the id of the submit button like this   <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit<button>

Answer (score 0):

1- first add the id attribute of the submit button id="submit"like this

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Submit<button>
```

2- update the code on user_check.php

```
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {    
if(!preg_match('/^([^0-9]*)$/', $_POST['user'])) {
    echo '<p style="color:red">Name contains a number</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p style="color:green"> You can take this name</p>';
}    
}
```